# Android - How to parse intent to json object?

Tags: android, json

I want to add my intent to json object, but how to do that with this code below

`Pojo.java`

```
    //getter and setter on above code
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("id", id);
        obj.put("nilai", ratingStar);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

`Main.java`

```
 for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
   jArray.put(adapter3.getItem(i).getJsonObject());
 }
JSONObject j=new JSONObject();
try {
  j.put("fishing",jArray);
  Log.d("json output : ",j.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the respone from `Log.d("json output : ",j.toString());` is :

```
{"fishing":[{"id":"1","nilai":1},{"id":"2","nilai":1},{"id":"3","nilai":1},{"id":"4","nilai":1},{"id":"5","nilai":1}]}
```

But i want to add my intent into json object like this

```
{"fishing":[{|"id_dosen":"2","id_matkul":"3"|,"id":"1","nilai":1},{|"id_dosen":"2","id_matkul":"3"|,"id":"2","nilai":1},{|"id_dosen":"2","id_matkul":"3"|,"id":"3","nilai":1},{|"id_dosen":"2","id_matkul":"3"|,"id":"4","nilai":1},{|"id_dosen":"2","id_matkul":"3"|,"id":"5","nilai":1}]}
```

can someone help me how to add the json that I mark with `|`??

**Note : i use `|` symbol just to let you guys easy to read what's the different from 1st json with 2nd json**

Comment: To clearify your question, you want to pass adding `id_dosen` and `id_matkul` to another intent. Is that what you want ?

Comment: actualy, on 1st activity, i've been use `i.putExtra("nomor_matkul", String.valueOf(id_matkul));` , then i want to add 1st activity intent to json object in 2nd activity, do you know what i mean?

Comment: **Please comment why you down vote my question!!!**

Comment: @dondo: if you add | after every value then JSONObject  become invalid

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i won't add that symbol `|` to json, i just use it to let you guys know what i want to add in json,

Comment: @dondo: What you are adding in `obj` same in getting in response,add `id_matkul` and `id_dosen` in `obj` in same way as adding `id`,`nilai`

Comment: yes, `id_matkul` and `id_dosen` value is same in each json object, but not with the `id`, because i use loop, i dont know how to add `id_matkul` and `id_dosen` to constant value in json

Comment: @dondo: Use `obj.put("id", id);obj.put("nilai", ratingStar);obj.put("id_matkul", 3);obj.put("id_dosen", 2);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i've used that in `Pojo.java`, but the `id_matkul` and `id_dosen` not show in logcat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131763/discussion-between--k-and-dondo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add those fields in your JSON like this.

```
String jsonFishing = "{\"fishing\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"nilai\":1},{\"id\":\"2\",\"nilai\":1},{\"id\":\"3\",\"nilai\":1},{\"id\":\"4\",\"nilai\":1},{\"id\":\"5\",\"nilai\":1}]}";
try {
  JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(jsonFishing);
  JSONArray fishingArr = rootObj.getJSONArray("fishing");
  for (int i = 0; i < fishingArr.length(); i++){
    JSONObject child = fishingArr.getJSONObject(i);
    child.put("id_dosen", 2);
    child.put("id_matkul", 3);
  }
  ...
  yourIntent.putExtra("json", rootObj.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Newly obtained JSON looks like this.

```
{"fishing":[{"id":"1","nilai":1,"id_dosen":2,"id_matkul":3},{"id":"2","nilai":1,"id_dosen":2,"id_matkul":3},{"id":"3","nilai":1,"id_dosen":2,"id_matkul":3},{"id":"4","nilai":1,"id_dosen":2,"id_matkul":3},{"id":"5","nilai":1,"id_dosen":2,"id_matkul":3}]}
```

Edit : In your code, it would be like this

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
   JSONObject jsonObject = adapter3.getItem(i).getJsonObject();
   jsonObject.put("id_dosen", 2);
   jsonObject.put("id_matkul", 3);
   jArray.put(jsonObject);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i've try that method like add `jArray.put("id_dosen", id_dosen);` and `jArray.put("id_matkul", id_matkul);` inside `for` loop, but it's not working